# SpriteGroup - adding muliple objects

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a sprite class where the user can define and add any number of sprites on to the screen from a random location using [this](http://sivasantosh.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/sprites-in-pygame-part-2/) tutorial. However, when I try to run my current program it puts the error

> AttributeError: type object 'Sprite' has no attribute 'sprite'

But I dont understand why, all the logic seems correct.

Any suggestions?

Heres my code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
pygame.init()

black = (0, 0, 0)
image = pygame.image.load("resources/images/img.png")

SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400

sprite_width = 5
sprite_height = 5

sprite_count = 5

# no changes here when using sprite groups



class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, Image, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image =pygame.image.load("resources/images/img.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = pos
        self.pygame.display.set_caption('Sprite Group Example')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        # this is a how sprite group is created
        self.sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 1
        self.rect.y += 2
        if self.rect.y > SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.y = -1 * sprtie_height
        if self.rect.x > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.x = -1 * sprite_width

    @classmethod  
    def sprites(self):
       for i in range(actor_count):
            tmp_x = random.randrange(0, SCREEN_WIDTH)
            tmp_y = random.randrange(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
            # all you have to do is add new sprites to the sprite group
            self.sprite.add(Sprite(image, [tmp_x, tmp_y]))

    @classmethod       
    def game_loop(self):
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 400])
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            screen.fill(black)

            # to update or blitting just call the groups update or draw
            # notice there is no for loop
            # this will automatically call the individual sprites update method

            self.sprite.update()
            self.sprite.draw(screen)

            self.pygame.display.update()
            self.clock.tick(20)

Sprite.sprites()
Sprite.game_loop()
```

Comment: A sprite is usually singular, and should therefore _not_ have a sprite group as a member variable. A sprite group should hold all the single sprites. Just like in the link you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define class method (`@classmethod`) but `self.sprite` exists only in object/instance not in class - it is created in `__init__` when you crate new object/instance.

Remove `@classmethod` to have object/instance method and have no problem with `self.sprite`.

Or create `sprite` outside `__init__` to get class attribute

```
class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def __init__(self, Image, pos)
        # instance variable - value copied from class variable
        print self.sprite 

        # class variable 
        print self.__class__.sprite 

    @classmethod  
    def sprites(self):
        # instance variable not exists

        # class variable 
        print self.sprite
```

Comment: how would i refer to the sprite variable in other methods like sprites, as it is now not a global variable

Comment: You can still use `self.sprite` - it is global variable in class and instance.

Comment: To change vaule of class attribute use `self.__class__` prefix, `self.__class__.sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()`

Comment: Thanks as always Furas